# Flutter Slider not rebuilding inside of ExpansionPanel

Tags: flutter, dart, material-design

I'm trying to create a form using multiple `ExpansionPanel`s in an `ExpansionPanelList`.
I initially set up the form in the page using `initState`.

Now the main issue I ran into is implementing a `Slider` widget into one of the `ExpansionPanel`.
The `Slider` button UI isn't updating on change, however, the value of the slider, `_colorValue`, is.

I think the issue is with the `ExpansionPanel` `body` not updating upon a rebuild, but I'm unsure how to resolve it.
I already read the docs with no real help.

Here is my code:

```
import ...

/// stores ExpansionPanel state information
class Panel {
  Panel({
    this.expandedValue,
    this.headerValue,
    this.isExpanded = false,
  });

  Widget expandedValue;
  String headerValue;
  bool isExpanded;
}

class AddReviewScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  static const String route = 'add_review_screen';
  @override
  _AddReviewScreenState createState() => _AddReviewScreenState();
}

class _AddReviewScreenState extends State<AddReviewScreen> {
  final _formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();
  double _colorValue = 1.0;
  List<Panel> _panels;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _panels = _getPanels();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        centerTitle: true,
        title: Text('Add Review', style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.display4),
        backgroundColor: kAppBarBackgroundColor,
      ),
      backgroundColor: kScaffoldBackgroundColor,
      body: SafeArea(
        child: SingleChildScrollView(
          child: Container(
            padding: EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
            child: Form(
              key: _formKey,
              child: _buildForm(),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  List<Panel> _getPanels() {
    return [
      Panel(...),
      Panel(
        headerValue: 'Sensory Features',
        expandedValue: Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            Slider(
              value: _colorValue,
              min: 0.0,
              max: 2.0,
              divisions: 20,
              onChanged: (double newValue) {
                setState(() {
                  _colorValue = newValue;
                  print(_colorValue);
                });
              },
            ),
            TextFormField(...),
            TextFormField(...),
            TextFormField(...),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    ];
  }

  Widget _buildForm() {
    return ExpansionPanelList(
      expansionCallback: (int index, bool isExpanded) {
        setState(() {
          _panels[index].isExpanded = !isExpanded;
        });
      },
      children: _panels.map<ExpansionPanel>((Panel panel) {
        return ExpansionPanel(
          headerBuilder: (BuildContext context, bool isExpanded) {
            return ListTile(
              title: Text(panel.headerValue),
            );
          },
          body: panel.expandedValue,
          isExpanded: panel.isExpanded,
        );
      }).toList(),
    );
  }
}
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated!
If there are any questions please let me know and I'll do my best to answer them.

Answer (score 0):

The issue was as I thought, in the line `body: panel.expandedValue`. Whenever a rebuild was triggered, the panels were getting redrawn from the `_panels` List, therefore, going back to their initial state.

How I managed to solve it was by first extracting each `expandedValue` from the Panels in `_getPanels`, into their own separate functions. Then, I refactored the `ExpansionPanelList`'s children from a dynamic Map/List to a static List of `ExpansionPanel`s since I know that the size of the list won't change in the future, therefore it had no reason for the dynamic functionality.

So essentially now whenever a rebuild occurs, the UI doesn't fall back to its initial state. Instead, it updates the "dirty" values in the extracted Widget functions.

Here is my solution:

```
  /// Construct the initial List of Panels.
  List<Panel> _getPanels() {
    return [
      Panel(
        headerValue: 'Panel 1',
        expandedValue: _panel1(),
        isExpanded: true,
      ),
      Panel(
        headerValue: 'Panel 2',
        expandedValue: _panel2(),
      ),
    ];
  }

  Function _expansionPanelHeaderBuilderCallback(String title) {
    return (BuildContext context, bool isExpanded) {
      return ListTile(
        title: Text(title),
      );
    };
  }

  Widget _buildForm() {
    return ExpansionPanelList(
      expansionCallback: (int index, bool isExpanded) {
        setState(() {
          _panels[index].isExpanded = !isExpanded;
        });
      },
      children: [
        ExpansionPanel(
          headerBuilder: _expansionPanelHeaderBuilderCallback(_panels[0].headerValue),
          body: _panel1(),
          isExpanded: _panels[0].isExpanded,
          canTapOnHeader: true,
        ),
        ExpansionPanel(
          headerBuilder:
              _expansionPanelHeaderBuilderCallback(_panels[1].headerValue),
          body: _panel2(),
          isExpanded: _panels[1].isExpanded,
          canTapOnHeader: true,
        ),
      ],
    );
  }

  Widget _panel1() {
    return Padding(...);
  }

  Widget _panel2() {
    return Column(...);
  }
```

Please if better solutions are found (as I'm sure there are), post them here and I'll mark them as the correct answer.